# Canvas API and Web worker

Tags: javascript, html, web, html5-canvas, web-worker

I know that canvas tags or any other tag can't be created inside of a web worker, but the web worker can make ajax calls.  Would it be more efficient when drawing images to create a web worker, have it do an ajax call to another file, that then generates a canvas and returns the data from "getImageData"?

Comment: I can't think of a case where routing through remote calls (ajax) would be more efficient than the direct messaging built into web workers.

Comment: No, it's faster to use main thread for this. We're talking about processor vs network speed, it's obvious!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do some processing on the data (that you will receive from ajax call) then only you should use a web worker . For example if you have to calculate the average price of stocks over a week and then display it as a bar chart and you have data of complete year then you can use a web worker for this . Otherwise there is no point of using a web worker just to make a ajax call only to return that data again to ui thread.

Comment: Thank you. Perfectly put

Comment: This answer is a little overly sure of itself. There are valid reasons for having a web worker make & manage the Ajax call. For instance, if your call is going to return 20 MB of JSON, it is more efficient to parse that JSON in the web worker and pass the parsed object to the UI thread.  That way the UI doesn't hang while handling the very long string.